# Safe explicit vectorization of a seemingly simple loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp, vectorization, simd

New here, hoping you can help. I am attempting to explicitly vectorize both of the for loops in the below member function code as they are the main runtime bottleneck and auto-vectorization does not work due to dependencies. For the life of me, however, I cannot find "safe" clause/reduction.

```
PSvector& RTMap::Apply(PSvector& X) const
{
    PSvector Y(0);
    double k=0;

    // linear map
    #pragma omp simd
    for(RMap::const_itor r = rterms.begin(); r != rterms.end(); r++)
    {
        Y[r->i] += r->val * X[r->j];
    }       

    // non-linear map
    #pragma omp simd
    for(const_itor t = tterms.begin(); t != tterms.end(); t++)
    {
        Y[t->i] += t->val * X[t->j] * X[t->k];
    }       

    Y.location() = X.location();
    Y.type() = X.type();
    Y.id() = X.id();
    Y.sd() = X.sd();

    return X = Y;
}
```

Note that the #pragmas as written don't work because of race conditions. Is there a method of declaring reduction which could work? I tried something like:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(+:PSvector:(*omp_out.getvec())+=(*omp_in.getvec()))
```

which compiles (icpc) but seems to produce nonsense.

/cheers

Comment: @Ruks Why? Do they prevent vectorization or is this a stylistic complaint?

Comment: @MaxLanghof They are redundant and the question does not ask to *prevent* vectorization...

Comment: @Ruks That's a matter of preference. And I believe it's bad advice in general.

Comment: @Ruks There is no point in predicating answers to a technical question on minor and topically irrelevant formatting preferences. I was giving you the benefit of the doubt with "do they prevent vectorization?" (then your comment would've been reasonable), not suggesting that they should be left in order to prevent it.

Comment: I can't see what the actual dependency structure of the calculation is through all that high level stuff

Comment: Different compilers are differently aggressive with SIMD optimization. Which compiler and what platform are you targeting?

Comment: This depends on the guaranties around `r->i` and `r->j`. If they can be any valid index then the order of calculation may be important which would make this loop non-parallelizable. You first need to be able to identify which calculations are independent before figuring out a parallelization strategy. Same with `t->i`, `t->j` and `t->k`.

Comment: As Francois pointed out, unless you set an ordered clause, the parallel iterations could be performed in any order.  With g++, the omp simd is likely only to suspend checking for potential aliases, but that is the main safety problem.  As your case is one which is likely not to be effectively vectorizable, g++ may not vectorize, and so not incur change in performance or order of operations.  Intel compiler would make a stronger effort to vectorize, without considering the desirabiiity.

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason of the error reported by your compiler, but your loops aren't in [canonical form](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#section.2.6). In order for the `omp simd` directive to be applicable, you need for example to replace your `!=` with `<` (assuming your iterator are random ones). Otherwise, I'm afraid you cannot vectorize like this.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your code. We even have to guess what kind of iterators are involved which the whole answer depends on. Please provide a [mcve] so we can discuss specific performance. It also helps to provide an idea of the target system/architecture.

Comment: If you're running on a platform with efficient scatter/gather operations, you may be able to vectorize this in principle. However, if `PSvector` is a growable container and writing to `Y[r->i]` can cause reallocation, you have to completely prevent reallocation in the loops, possibly by pre-allocating. If you cannot prevent reallocation, vectorizing this is probably not practical.

Comment: As Gilles pointed out, attempting to vectorize a loop using != as an ending condition is non-portable and will not work as often as the standard syntax which clearly allows the OpenMP runtime to calculate and divide up the iterations in advance. On account of C++ tradition, compilers need to handle != optimization to some extent, but the use of it tends to signal a case which you don't expect to be vectorizable.

Comment: Make your code look like C instead of C++. It's easier to see how C will be converted to machine code. C++ obfuscates that.

Comment: Looking at the first loop, you have 3 gather loads (X, Y, val) and one scattered store (Y). This is expensive on most architectures. You won't amortize much of this cost with parallelizing just one multiplication and one sum. Not sure it is worth it. Your best chances are to re-engineer your data structure to make it suitable for parallelizzation.